# what is the minimum number of conjugacy classes for a group of order $n!$?

Tags: group-theory

i became curious about how one might measure the extent to which a given finite group departs from perfect commutativity. a rough-and-ready index of the degree to which a group $G$ is commutative may be computed as the proportion of ordered pairs $(g_1,g_2) \in G \times G$ for which $g_1g_2 = g_2 g_1$

calculating this index, let us call it $\kappa$, turned out to be simpler than i had anticipated. described in words, the probability of two randomly sampled elements commuting is equal to the number of conjugacy classes divided by the order of the group.

let $\Gamma (=\Gamma_G)$ denote the set of conjugacy classes of the finite group $G$. for every element $g$ of $G$ belonging to $\gamma \in \Gamma$ the number of elements of $G$ which commute with $g$ is the order of $G_g$, the centralizer of $g$. by a basic result of group theory:
$$
|G_g| = \frac{|G|}{|\gamma|}
$$
thus the probability that a randomly-chosen pair of elements of $G$ commute (sampling *with* replacement) is:
$$
\kappa(G) = \frac{\sum_{g \in G} |G_g|}{|G|^2} \\
 = \frac{|\Gamma_G|}{|G|}  \\
$$
in particular for symmetric groups we have:
$$
\kappa(S_n) = \frac{P(n)}{n!}
$$
where $P(n)$ is the number of partitions of $n$

**question** is $P(n)$ the minimum number of conjugacy classes for a group of order $n!$, and if so, how can this be demonstrated?

Comment: A somewhat shorter proof is to use Burnside's lemma on the action of $G$ on itself by conjugation. This tells you that the number of conjugacy classes is $\frac{1}{|G|}$ times the number of commuting pairs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. For example, the [Mathieu group $M_{10}$](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Mathieu_group:M10) has order $6! = 720$, the [same](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Special:Ask/-5B-5Barithmetic-20function-20value::order-20of-20a-20group;720-5D-5D/-3FGAP-20ID) as the order of $S_6$, but $M_{10}$ has $8$ conjugacy classes while $S_6$ has $11$.

You can find a paper on the general question (for groups of various orders) [here](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~boston/finalgps.pdf).

Comment: thank you for that answer, and for the reference

Comment: Name of "here":  [Boston and Walker - 2-groups with few conjugacy classes](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0013091500020824) (an instance where a hyphen in a title makes a big difference!).